# Rake task w/ splat arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm attempting to create a rake task that takes a required first argument, and then any number of additional arguments which I want to lump together into an array:

```
rake course["COURSE NAME", 123, 456, 789]
```

I've tried the following but `args[:numbers]` is simply a string w/ `123` instead of all of the numbers.

```
task :course, [:name, *:numbers] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts args # {:name=>"COURSE NAME", :numbers=>"123"}
end
```

Comment: How about `rake course["COURSE NAME", [123, 456, 789]]`?

Comment: That gives me `{:name=>"COURSE NAME", :numbers=>"[123"}` which is really bizarre.

Comment: No spaces are allowed between the arguments for the tasks, try this: `rake course["COURSE NAME",123,456,789]`

Comment: Nope. Gives me `{:name=>"COURSE NAME", :numbers=>"123"}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting with rake 10.1.0 you can use [`Rake::TaskArguments#extras`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/Rake/TaskArguments.html#method-i-extras):

```
task :environment

task :course, [:name] => :environment do |t, args|
  name = args[:name]
  numbers = args.extras
  puts "name = #{name}"
  puts "numbers = #{numbers.join ','}"
end
```

Output:

```
$ rake "course[COURSE NAME, 123, 456, 789]"
name = COURSE NAME
numbers = 123,456,789
```

For rake < 10.1.0 you could create a sufficienty large argument list.

Here's a workaround for up to 26 numbers:

```
task :course, [:name, *:a..:z] => :environment do |t, args|
  name = args[:name]
  numbers = args.values_at(*:a..:z).compact
  puts "name = #{name}"
  puts "numbers = #{numbers.join ','}"
end
```

Comment: This does not work. I've tried `rake course["COURSE NAME",123,456,789]` as well as `rake course["COURSE NAME",[123,456,789]]` and in both cases `args.extras` is `nil`

Comment: Seems like [this feature](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/pull/150) was introduced in rake 10.1.0, maybe you have to update

Comment: This works when using 10.1.0 our server is currently running 10.0.3. Is there a solution that doesn't use the `extras` method?

Comment: @KyleDecot added a hack for rake < 10.1.0 to my answer